# Pycharm auto-import is not following best practice?

Tags: python, import, pycharm

We recently had a talk about removing any circular imports we might have and refactoring our code to not use imports inside functions anymore.

One of the ways that is recommended for this in many places (including PEP-8 style guide [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - under imports) is to use:

```
import a 
a.foo()
```

instead of:

```
from a import foo
foo()
```

I saw some examples and got convinced that this is probably a better way to do the imports (even though im used to the `from` way of importing).

But I dont understand is how come 99% of python examples dont use this way of importing. And why my pycharm is not allowing auto-import in this manner (or is it?) if this is the right way to import.

Looking into pycharm configurations, I didnt find a way to auto-complete with `import y.x` instead of `from y import x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `import x` instead of `from y import x`. You must use `import x.y` if `y` is a submodule, or `import x; a = x.y` if `y` is a variable (class, function, constant ...)
To make Pycharm auto complete with the root module name, you have to start typing the root module name instead of the sub-element you want to use.
By exemple, if you want to use the `split` function of `os.path`, if you start typing `split` and then hit double `CTRL-SPACE`, Pycharm will auto-import with `from os.path import split`. But if you start typing `os`, Pycharm will auto-complete with `import os` and the you can end your statement with `.path.split`

Comment: about the first part, I meant `import x.y`. about the pycharm, I understand - and i'll use that. but it sucks that I dont have the option to choose that from the import dropdown because I find myself a lo of times knowing the name of the function\class that I want to use but not the package that its in (I let pycharm show me the options)

Comment: Indeed. You can use the auto-import with `from` in the first place, and when you are done, you can hit `alt-enter` on the import statement and choose `convert to import module`